# Getting a string from url split after a character c#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use a url to post a username back and fourth from another page. My current code (which gives an error "StartIndex cannot be less than zero.".

```
if (Convert.ToString(Context.Request.QueryString).StartsWith("username"))
                {
                    string username = Convert.ToString(Context.Request.QueryString);
                    string input = username.Substring(username.LastIndexOf(":"));
                    txt_username.Text = input;
                }
```

the url looks like 192.168.1.1/p/login.aspx?username:textIwantintxtbox

Obviously just trying to put the last bit into a text box.

Comment: Are you sure its a colon? normally get parameters use an equals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be taking a longer way to get the value you actually want. Since you start with a [`QueryString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx), you should just use that.

```
txt_username.Text = Context.Request.QueryString['username'];
```

---

As for your actual error, `Substring` needs to start from at least index 0, `LastIndexOf` seems to be returning -1, indicating it hasn't found the colon, probably because `get` parameters normally use an `=` instead of a `:`